# Return Mysql data in return of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm a beginner and don't really understand how to use asynchronous functions.

The function's 'return' does not return the data I need when I call this function.

What is the correct way to make this function and the return of Mysql appear in the function's return when called?

```
async function username(user_id){
    let [rows, fields] = await dbConnection.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=?', [user_id]);

    //console.log(rows);

    return rows[0].name;
}
```

Comment: First, what does `console.log(rows);` return?

Comment: i think it's `dbConnection.query('query', [user_id])`. after that you need to check if `return rows[0] && rows[0].name` could work I'm guessing

Comment: In console.log(rows) return all data, but only in return no @suchislife

Comment: @HalilÇakar return only a Promise

Comment: Did you actually promissify your query's with utils so that you can use it as async/await?

Comment: How do you call the function? Since it is an async function, you'll have to `await` it or attach a `.then`.